# Is there a way to increase the performance of MySql in Docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

MySql performance is very slow in docker, so is there a way to increase its performance?

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of database are you trying to run? Which is your host operating system? How many data are you managing? Your question is too generic so far that it won't let us give a useful answer.

Comment: This might help: https://phpforus.com/how-to-make-mysql-run-fast-with-ext4-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Docker? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @J. Scott Elblein